# AuthorizeRequestValidator: Error: Invalid grant type for client: implicit

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am trying to setting up Identity Server 4 `HybridAndClientCredentials` on .NET Core 2.0 MVC.

I'm struggling with the error:

> Invalid grant type for client: implicit

Even though I have in my code:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
```

I have downloaded sample quickstart, and that is working properly, but I am unable to find with my code, what the chunk of line is missing.

Debug output:

```
IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator:
Error: Invalid grant type for client: implicit
{
  "ClientId": "consultee",
  "ClientName": "consultee Client test",
  "RedirectUri": "http://consultee.mi.local:44352/signin-oidc",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://consultee.mi.local:44352/signin-oidc"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "id_token",
  "ResponseMode": "form_post",
  "GrantType": "implicit",
  "RequestedScopes": "",
  "State": "CfDJ8KERs5ihv_5Ll9ddYi6Nj5lkLNGQptrJwHqbSD11g27zqVxPcKxLKvbMtd5ab5LPbV15yaCNlHlzpPgRQL4R2XSue8ka_fqLBWFfXad-sRNCyY03JxgL7HZDKDrph-G4hdvRRMvBtXUc0tq2tHd7ZGX7-djehs8aHD6-P_80UfFplHCYkvARV7I64Kb5ki4cFVmLE6G8EbWIUwir6HJpkgK1CbN_IuPtBTjaLZoBOEzpxWTRVaudsD4vZFxdTv4N51ufkn8jy7GPC0pf3xCGInQpA-FziHp681qmiWbCxlp9HuAIZBem-at9dNvC29yRBw4JbcoTSrjuHkq6G6gZtXVh1YuuQYIW9R4wklmlSEX4i8kxM8zJTog98Ce3OFsYnw",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "consultee",
    "redirect_uri": "http://consultee.mi.local:44352/signin-oidc",
    "response_type": "id_token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1 offline_access",
    "response_mode": "form_post",
    "nonce": "636626718480261618.MDYwZjE0MjMtNzczMi00ZjQ4LTk0NWUtZjQ1ZDNjM2VjZTRhOWI0NWM0MjMtNGM3Ni00ZDA3LWIyZDctMDcwNTc3ZDU0NGYy",
    "state": "CfDJ8KERs5ihv_5Ll9ddYi6Nj5lkLNGQptrJwHqbSD11g27zqVxPcKxLKvbMtd5ab5LPbV15yaCNlHlzpPgRQL4R2XSue8ka_fqLBWFfXad-sRNCyY03JxgL7HZDKDrph-G4hdvRRMvBtXUc0tq2tHd7ZGX7-djehs8aHD6-P_80UfFplHCYkvARV7I64Kb5ki4cFVmLE6G8EbWIUwir6HJpkgK1CbN_IuPtBTjaLZoBOEzpxWTRVaudsD4vZFxdTv4N51ufkn8jy7GPC0pf3xCGInQpA-FziHp681qmiWbCxlp9HuAIZBem-at9dNvC29yRBw4JbcoTSrjuHkq6G6gZtXVh1YuuQYIW9R4wklmlSEX4i8kxM8zJTog98Ce3OFsYnw",
    "x-client-SKU": "ID_NET",
    "x-client-ver": "2.1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Client:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "consultee",
    ClientName = "consultee Client test",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris = { "http://consultee.mi.local:44352/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://consultee.mi.local:44352/signout-callback-oidc" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    },
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
}
```

`ConfigurationService` at Client:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies")
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = Configuration["identityServerUri"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "consultee";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        });
}
```

`ConfigurationService` at `IdServer`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

        services.AddAuthentication();

    }
```

Comment: sorry! I don't understand exactly, but that is worked for me :  
offline_access  and  **options.ResponseType = "code id_token token";** (at client)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The log tells you what that problem is

> Error: Invalid grant type for client: implicit

You are logging in as an implicit client.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = Configuration["identityServerUri"];
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "consultee";
            options.ClientSecret = "secret";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
        });
```

You have configured a hybrid client in the identity server

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "consultee",
                ClientName = "consultee Client test",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris = { "http://consultee.migrology.local:44352/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://consultee.migrology.local:44352/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            }
```

So the server isnt going to allow you to do this.  You need to change your code to login as hybrid or alter your client to be an implicit client.

**Change to hybrid**

In order to change an implicit login to a hybrid login you need to change a few things.

- configure the ClientSecret to match the secret at IdentityServer.
- Add the offline_access
- add a scope (api1)
- set the ResponseType to `code id_token` (which basically means “use hybrid flow”)    **(you are missing this)**

Comment: you are really with bull eyes!

Comment: I am working on the same thing and i thought it was strange your project was using implicit and mine runs hybrid so i had to test with your code.   We both learned something here.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue can occur when you make a typo in the "username" in the form data. Especially dreadful are the typos when you use cyrillic letters.